# Gibt es einen Bedeutungsunterschied zwischen „sinnvoll“ und „sinnstiftend“?

Tags: meaning

Es besteht meines Wissens keiner, aber ich wollte trotzdem die Frage Muttersprachlern stellen, die natürlich viel besser Bescheid wissen. Vielleicht gibt es irgendeinen Zusammenhang, in dem eins davon zu bevorzugen ist.

Comment: *Sinnvoll* ist ein Zustand, *sinnstiftend* ein Vorgang. Damit etwas sinnvoll sein kann, muss zuerst Sinn gestiftet worden sein.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Von meiner Seite aus sind das sehr ähnliche Wörter, aber tatsächlich hat es nicht exakt dieselbe Bedeutung. Ich bin natürlich auch kein Sprachwissenschaftler, sei dazu gesagt. So aus meiner Einschätzung:

Erstmal sei gesagt, „sinnvoll“ ist deutlich gängiger im deutschen Sprachgebrauch.

„Sinnvoll“: Wenn eine bestimmte Sache oder eine Tat einen brauchbaren Zweck erfüllt.

„Sinnstiftend“: Wenn durch eine bestimmte Sache oder eine Tat ein Sinn entsteht.

Ich würde behaupten, dass ich darin eine Unterscheidung sehe. Ein Beispiel wäre die Anschaffung eines Haustieres, wo die Durchführung des Aktes „sinnvoll“ wäre und „sinnstiftend“ ist ein Adjektiv, was sich eher auf die Folgen von etwas bezieht.

Zum Beispiel:
Den Hund zu sich zu holen und für das Haustier Spaß und Vorfreude zu fühlen, macht die Anschaffung sinnvoll.
Spaß und Vorfreude sind sinnstiftende Gefühle dieser Anschaffung.